# discerning between "his saying that" and "him saying that"

Tags: verbs, clauses

Excerpted from Oxford dictionary:

A. I can just imagine him saying that!

Which one is more formal, or which one have you seen more in formal texts? In addition, do you use them interchangeably?

B. I can just imagine his saying that!

Any feed-back would greatly be appreciated

Comment: In texts, "his saying" is more common. In daily conversation, "him saying" is more common.  For many years, students were taught that "his" was correct and "him" was incorrect. You may find textbooks still making the distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be used interchangeably. There is a difference in style/register though. *His* is more formal and/or written style, while in spoken language you'll mostly hear *him*. Nevertheless, both are correct so it is up to you to decide which one is most appropriate in the context.